# xml to sql with openxml

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, soap, openxml

quisiera consultar desde sql, este xml y pueda dar el resultado de una tabla los campos que están dentro del Body:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"
    xmlns:e="http://www.technisys.net/cmm/services/errors/v1.0" xmlns:md="http://www.technisys.net/cmm/services/metadata/v2.0"
    xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd"
    xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
    <SOAP-ENV:Header>
     <md:metadata><traceNumber>191750</traceNumber>
         <serviceId>processSystemUserLoginByCustomerMigration</serviceId>
         <serviceVersion>0.0</serviceVersion>
         <sessionId>OAUTH2_58f93b26-f876-42ab-aa41-2c9d482a199f_rriosc@bancofalabella.com.pe</sessionId>
         <targetChannel>
             <mnemonic>PF</mnemonic>
         </targetChannel>
         <executingChannel>
             <mnemonic>PF</mnemonic>
         </executingChannel>
         <address>ip=10.255.0.2;</address>
         <sourceDate>20190201101319013</sourceDate>
         <channelDispatchDate>xxxxxxxxxxxx</channelDispatchDate>
         <locale>es_AR</locale>
         <featureId>ROL@4702</featureId>
         <institutionType>UNDEFINED</institutionType>
         <msgTypeId>200</msgTypeId>
         <terminalId>browser=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.98 Safari/537.36;platform=;subChannel=;terminalCode=;</terminalId>
         <organizationId></organizationId>
         <organizationOperatorId>uriTech=OPERADOR_BANCO@9884015;uriSFB=150059641;branchCode=209;execUser=rriosc@bancofalabella.com.pe;execCodePosition=4;execNamePosition=EECC;execCodeRole=3;execNameRole=Ejecutivos Comerciales;</organizationOperatorId>
         <executingOperatorId>uriTech=OPERADOR_BANCO@9884015;uriSFB=150059641;branchCode=209;execUser=rriosc@bancofalabella.com.pe;execCodePosition=4;execNamePosition=EECC;execCodeRole=3;execNameRole=Ejecutivos Comerciales;</executingOperatorId>
         <paginationInfo></paginationInfo>
         <branchId>1</branchId>
         <userId></userId>
         <parityCurrencyId />
         <localCurrencyId />
         <localCountryId />
         <bankId />
         <organizationType/>
     </md:metadata>

    </SOAP-ENV:Header>
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
     <srv:processSystemUserLoginByCustomerMigrationRequest xmlns:srv="http://www.technisys.net/cmm/services/processSystemUserLoginByCustomerMigration/rq/v0.0">
     <generic><sessionId type="java.lang.String">OAUTH2_58f93b26-f876-42ab-aa41-2c9d482a199f_rriosc@bancofalabella.com.pe</sessionId><forceToAdhere type="java.lang.Boolean">false</forceToAdhere></generic><customer name="customer"><identificationNumber>12345678</identificationNumber><identificationType><mnemonic>DNI</mnemonic></identificationType></customer>
     </srv:processSystemUserLoginByCustomerMigrationRequest>
  </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Mi tabla resultado tendria que ser
identificationNumber | identificationType
12345678               DNI

Answer (score 0):

Puedes realizarlo de la siguiente manera, en donde `@info` es el valor de tu XML. si necesitas mayor apoyo para la interpretación de nodos XML en SQL Server revisa el siguiente [link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/xml/nodes-method-xml-data-type?view=sql-server-2017):

```
DECLARE @info XML = '<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"
    xmlns:e="http://www.technisys.net/cmm/services/errors/v1.0" xmlns:md="http://www.technisys.net/cmm/services/metadata/v2.0"
    xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd"
    xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
    <SOAP-ENV:Header>
     <md:metadata><traceNumber>191750</traceNumber>
         <serviceId>processSystemUserLoginByCustomerMigration</serviceId>
         <serviceVersion>0.0</serviceVersion>
         <sessionId>OAUTH2_58f93b26-f876-42ab-aa41-2c9d482a199f_rriosc@bancofalabella.com.pe</sessionId>
         <targetChannel>
             <mnemonic>PF</mnemonic>
         </targetChannel>
         <executingChannel>
             <mnemonic>PF</mnemonic>
         </executingChannel>
         <address>ip=10.255.0.2;</address>
         <sourceDate>20190201101319013</sourceDate>
         <channelDispatchDate>xxxxxxxxxxxx</channelDispatchDate>
         <locale>es_AR</locale>
         <featureId>ROL@4702</featureId>
         <institutionType>UNDEFINED</institutionType>
         <msgTypeId>200</msgTypeId>
         <terminalId>browser=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.98 Safari/537.36;platform=;subChannel=;terminalCode=;</terminalId>
         <organizationId></organizationId>
         <organizationOperatorId>uriTech=OPERADOR_BANCO@9884015;uriSFB=150059641;branchCode=209;execUser=rriosc@bancofalabella.com.pe;execCodePosition=4;execNamePosition=EECC;execCodeRole=3;execNameRole=Ejecutivos Comerciales;</organizationOperatorId>
         <executingOperatorId>uriTech=OPERADOR_BANCO@9884015;uriSFB=150059641;branchCode=209;execUser=rriosc@bancofalabella.com.pe;execCodePosition=4;execNamePosition=EECC;execCodeRole=3;execNameRole=Ejecutivos Comerciales;</executingOperatorId>
         <paginationInfo></paginationInfo>
         <branchId>1</branchId>
         <userId></userId>
         <parityCurrencyId />
         <localCurrencyId />
         <localCountryId />
         <bankId />
         <organizationType/>
     </md:metadata>
    </SOAP-ENV:Header>

    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
     <srv:processSystemUserLoginByCustomerMigrationRequest xmlns:srv="http://www.technisys.net/cmm/services/processSystemUserLoginByCustomerMigration/rq/v0.0">
        <generic>
            <sessionId type="java.lang.String">OAUTH2_58f93b26-f876-42ab-aa41-2c9d482a199f_rriosc@bancofalabella.com.pe</sessionId>
            <forceToAdhere type="java.lang.Boolean">false</forceToAdhere>
        </generic>
        <customer name="customer">
            <identificationNumber>12345678</identificationNumber>
            <identificationType>
                <mnemonic>DNI</mnemonic>
            </identificationType>
        </customer>
    </srv:processSystemUserLoginByCustomerMigrationRequest>
  </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>'


SELECT r.value('identificationNumber[1]','int') AS identificationNumber
      ,r.value('identificationType[1]','varchar(max)') AS identificationType      
FROM @info.nodes('/*:Envelope/*:Body/*:processSystemUserLoginByCustomerMigrationRequest/customer') AS A(r)
```